# Precise meaning of the cue-ball being "snookered"

Tags: snooker

The WPBSA rules define "snookered" as the following:

> **17. Snookered**
>
> The cue-ball is snookered when a direct stroke in a straight line to every ball on is wholly or partially obstructed by a ball or balls not on. If one or more balls on can be hit at both extreme edges free of obstruction by any ball not on, the cue-ball is not snookered.

With this in mind, consider the following scenarios, where the red balls are "on":

| Name | Image | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | [image: scenario A] | The cue ball cannot hit the red ball on the extreme right edge, but the whole ball is "visible" from the point of cue ball. |
| B | [image: scenario B] | The red ball is partially obscured by the yellow. |
| C | [image: scenario C] | The "far" red ball is obstructed by the "near" red ball (which is obviously also "on"). If the nearer red ball is removed, the cue ball will not be able to strike the farther red ball on the extreme edge (scenario A). |
| D | [image: scenario D] | The "far" red ball is obstructed by both the "near" red and the yellow. If the nearer red ball is removed, the yellow red ball would partially obscure the farther (scenario B). |
| E | [image: scenario E] | The "far" red ball is obstructed only by other red balls. If the middle and nearest red balls are removed, the "possible angles" would be at least as wide as if the farthest ball was the only one. |

My question is: which of these scenarios are considered "snookered" by the rules (resulting in a free ball if encountered after a foul, etc.). Are there any other special cases I overlooked?

---

<sub>This question was inspired by the answers to [these](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/28604/) [two](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/24948) questions which aren't clear in the matter, and also by [this image on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_snooker#/media/File:Snooker_Freeball.png) which states that the red is snookered by the black.</sub>

Comment: A-B-C-D seem to be snookered red balls, because they can't "*be hit at both extreme edges free of obstruction by any ball not on*". The angle of the sight must be wider I believe, like on [this image](https://imgur.com/a/Ew6cYlA): the dark lines show the ball is full sight, but light lines show it can't be hit of the right side, because of the yellow ball. As for you last example, we'd have to draw the lines to see if it fits I believe. Added as a comment as I don't know if it's enough for an answer...

Comment: @OldPadawan - images A and C show the "wider" angle of sight, they're included precisely for the reasons you mentioned (the "shadows" touching the red ball in image A represent the cue ball striking the red on the extreme edge). If you're sure that ABCD are all snookers and E is not, ideally with a source, then that would be enough for me to warrant an accepted answer.

Comment: well, I'm conducting more research right now, because that's *my* call, and it isn't 100% positive, and I don't want a tick on a bad answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [EPA - English Pool Association](https://www.epa.org.uk/rules/snookers.php) in their "*Foul Snookers and Foul Jaw Snookers*" section, your following situations are:

1. **A**: This situation **IS** a "foul snooker" to the player on reds, but not if taking a shot that does not follow a foul.
2. **B**: This situation **IS** a "foul snooker" to the player on reds but not if taking a shot that does not follow a foul.
3. **C**: This situation **IS** a "foul snooker" to the player on reds, but not if taking a shot that does not follow a foul.
4. **D**: This situation **IS** a "foul snooker" to the player on reds but not if taking a shot that does not follow a foul.
5. **E**: This situation **IS NOT** a "foul snooker" to the player on reds, as you cannot be snookered by a ball of your own colour.

Comment: Are you sure about points B and D? After reading through the article you linked, it seems that none of the situations A-D are "total snookers' as defined by the article, since you can  strike the left edge of a red with a straight shot, in all situations.

Comment: it seems this is, *after* a foul, but not before a regular shot.

Comment: After carefully reading the article I'm pretty sure that A-D are all "foul snookers'" (snookers after a foul), and *none* of A-E are "total snookers'" (snookers' after a regular shot) - there's always a straight line to directly hit a red. Since the article has excellent explanations, if you correct your answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: (I noticed I have messed up the "shadow" of yellow ball in D, it's too straight; it should look more like B. I will correct it later)

Comment: Humm... I don't get it the way you see it. After a foul, you need to be able to hit both edges on the finest cut. ABCD should therefore be "foul snookered" balls. B & D are also a regular snookered ones according to image #2 from the link, don't you think?

Comment: I believe B & D are situations similar to image #3 from the link, not #2: 
[here](https://i.imgur.com/sSobaGN.png) [are](https://i.imgur.com/v32UJtN.png) [some](https://i.imgur.com/JjmITpC.png) images that show that reds in B & D are directly hittable.

Comment: Maybe you should include/modify the images, either in your question or in the answer, or both?